# Posting Images with a SOAP Web Service (Windows Mobile)

Tags: windows-mobile, soap, post, mime

We are developing a Windows Mobile 6 Professional application which captures images and then needs to submit those images to a server (there will be between one and ten images at about 200KB each), along with a bunch of text-based metadata. The organization that runs the environment prefers SOAP to be used for this communication, though there is a chance that we could negotiate something different.

Anyway, I am having determining the best way to do this. I have never used MIME attachments before and I'm a little hazy on how exactly it would work in this scenario and whether it is the best design decision.

I was hoping to get some commentary on what my options are, and what the best option might be. Keep in mind that the connection might be flaky (cellular) and will not be particularly fast (estimated to be 2Mbit or less).

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using email:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage( "dave@email.com", Properties.Settings.Default.email);
message.Subject = "Picture # " + picnumber;
message.Body = "Metadata etc.";

Attachment data = new Attachment( picnumber.ToString() + ".jpg", new System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg );
data.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;

// Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
message.Attachments.Add( data );
```